# Inner Div with larger width than outer div

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have an Outer Div with a size:1200px, and within this div that I wanted to have an Inner Div that is wider, just for the purpose of fitting more horizontal stuff into a window.

As of right now the following CSS is not achieving this. Any tips appreciated.

```css
.OuterDiv {
  width: 1200px;
}
.InnerDiv {
  width: 1400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="OuterDiv">
  <div class="InnerDiv"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will make scrolling inside outerdiv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. I added `height` and `background` so you could see the boxes.

> The key is `overflow: auto`

```css
.OuterDiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 140px;
  background: blue;
  overflow: auto;
}
.InnerDiv {
  width: 1400px;
  height: 90%;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="OuterDiv">
  <div class="InnerDiv"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're just not vizualising, but to add, try adding the **overflow** property and some colors:

```
.OuterDiv {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #f00;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.InnerDiv {
  width: 1400px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #0f0;
}
```